# Graphene Django image field get absolute path

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I have an image field in my Django model and I am trying to get absolute path of the image field output from Graphene. I remember getting the absolute uri of a file/image field using `HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri`. So, I decided to use the same function in Graphene Django:

```
class PersonType(DjangoObjectType):
    def resolve_photo(self, info, **kwargs):
        print(info.context) # WSGIRequest
        print(info.context.build_absolute_uri(self.photo)) # Error here
        return self.photo

    class Meta:
       model = Person
```

Because the request here is not Django's HttpRequest (it is WSGI Request), I am not able to use some utility functions of Django's request.

Is there a way to create HttpRequest from WSGIRequest or is there some other way of building full URLs in Graphene Django? Reading docs, source code, or resources in the internet, I am not able to find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is there a way to create HttpRequest from WSGIRequest..?*

`WSGIRequest` inherits from `django.http.HttpRequest` so, you should be able to use all "public" utility functions of Django's request.

So having there a `WSGIRequest` is not your real problem. If `info.context` is really a `WSGIRequest`, you should can:

```
 info.context.build_absolute_uri(self.photo)
```

without any problems.

#### My guess

I've to guess here since you don't post the error you're receiving, that the problem is in `self.photo`.

Comment: That still doesn't provide absolute URL. It provides URL like this: `/media/people/pic.jpg`. I need it to show `http://localhost:8000/media/people/pic.jpg`.

Comment: I've edited my answer it would be very helpful if you post the stack trace of your the error.

Comment: I guess I made a typo earlier and it works like this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks It's work and the specific typo is:

```
    def resolve_image(self, info):
        """Resolve product image absolute path"""
        if self.image:
            self.image = info.context.build_absolute_uri(self.image.url)
        return self.image
```